# Passing the value of variable to another page by using button PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm beginner in PHP MySQL, 
I would like to ask how can I pass the value of variable to another page 
for example:
I have input form where all dropdown this will be use for search condition.
It is possible to call the variable with value of SQL query like this:

In this sample, I set the **`$sql`** to `Page1.php` and I want to call it in `Page2.php`

```
$sql = "SELECT * table 
WHERE column1 = '".$variable1."'
AND column2 = '".$variable2."'
AND column3 = '".$variable3."' ";
```

**OR**

If this kind of condition can be can be call or transfer or pass to another page?

```
if ($result=mysql_query($sql)) {
          $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
             if($query_num_rows == 0){ 
                echo "<script> alert('No Records Found!')</script>"; 
      } else { 
          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

I'm doing this to because I want to have separate code for generating to csv due to if I use this in the same page due to ff:

- *It only prompt blank page and automatically generate report without asking for conditions.*
- *I can't view the search form User Interface*
- *It also generate the codes to the csv*

For more info here is my all codes:

**report.php**

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  include_once "dbconnect.php";
  date_default_timezone_set('Hongkong');

           //Validate Login
            $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
            $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
          if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
            {
                header("Location: index.php");
            }//end of Validation Login

           //Setting up Variables for Search form
          if (isset($_POST['generate'])) {

          $month = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['month']));
          $year = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['year']));
          $status = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']));


          if (empty($month) && empty($year) && empty($status)) {
          echo '<script>alert(\'Select atleast 1 filter\')</script>'; 
          exit;        
         }

         //condition of search
         //Single Search
         if (!empty($month)) {
         $sql = "SELECT `subscribers`.`cus_id`,  `subscribers`.`fName`, `subscribers`.`lName`,`transactions`.`month`,
         `transactions`.`year`, `transactions`.`subscriptionStart`,`transactions`.`subscriptionEnd`,`transactions`.`subsStatus` 
          FROM `subscribers` 
          INNER JOIN `transactions`
          ON `subscribers`.`cus_id` = `transactions`.`cus_id` 
          WHERE 
          `transactions`.`month` = '".$month."'
          ORDER BY `cus_id` ASC ";

         } if (!empty($year)) {
          $sql = "SELECT `subscribers`.`cus_id`,  `subscribers`.`fName`, `subscribers`.`lName`,`transactions`.`month`,
         `transactions`.`year`, `transactions`.`subscriptionStart`,`transactions`.`subscriptionEnd`,`transactions`.`subsStatus` 
          FROM `subscribers` 
          INNER JOIN `transactions`
          ON `subscribers`.`cus_id` = `transactions`.`cus_id` 
          WHERE 
          `transactions`.`year` = '".$year."'
          ORDER BY `cus_id` ASC ";

         } if (!empty($status)) {               
        $sql = "SELECT `subscribers`.`cus_id`,  `subscribers`.`fName`, `subscribers`.`lName`,`transactions`.`month`,
         `transactions`.`year`, `transactions`.`subscriptionStart`,`transactions`.`subscriptionEnd`,`transactions`.`subsStatus` 
          FROM `subscribers` 
          INNER JOIN `transactions`
          ON `subscribers`.`cus_id` = `transactions`.`cus_id` 
          WHERE 
          `transactions`.`status` = '".$status."'
          ORDER BY `cus_id` ASC ";

         //Compound Search

         } if (!empty($month) && !empty($year)) {
           $sql = "SELECT `subscribers`.`cus_id`,  `subscribers`.`fName`, `subscribers`.`lName`,`transactions`.`month`,
         `transactions`.`year`, `transactions`.`subscriptionStart`,`transactions`.`subscriptionEnd`,`transactions`.`subsStatus` 
          FROM `subscribers` 
          INNER JOIN `transactions`
          ON `subscribers`.`cus_id` = `transactions`.`cus_id` 
          WHERE 
          `transactions`.`month` = '".$month."'  
          AND `transactions`.`year` = '".$year."'
          ORDER BY `cus_id` ASC ";

         } if (!empty($month) && !empty($status)) {
           $sql = "SELECT `subscribers`.`cus_id`,  `subscribers`.`fName`, `subscribers`.`lName`,`transactions`.`month`,
         `transactions`.`year`, `transactions`.`subscriptionStart`,`transactions`.`subscriptionEnd`,`transactions`.`subsStatus` 
          FROM `subscribers` 
          INNER JOIN `transactions`
          ON `subscribers`.`cus_id` = `transactions`.`cus_id` 
          WHERE 
          `transactions`.`month` = '".$month."'  
          AND `transactions`.`status` = '".$status."'
          ORDER BY `cus_id` ASC ";

         } if (!empty($month) && !empty($status) && !empty($year)) {
           $sql = "SELECT `subscribers`.`cus_id`,  `subscribers`.`fName`, `subscribers`.`lName`,`transactions`.`month`,
         `transactions`.`year`, `transactions`.`subscriptionStart`,`transactions`.`subscriptionEnd`,`transactions`.`subsStatus` 
          FROM `subscribers` 
          INNER JOIN `transactions`
          ON `subscribers`.`cus_id` = `transactions`.`cus_id` 
          WHERE 
          `transactions`.`month` = '".$month."'  
          AND `transactions`.`status` = '".$status."'
          AND `transactions`.`year` = '".$year."'
          ORDER BY `cus_id` ASC ";  

      } 

      //Is this possible to transfer to another page? I'll be using this for generate.csv
      //FROM here
      if ($result=mysql_query($sql)) {
          $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
             if($query_num_rows == 0){ 
                echo "<script> alert('No Records Found!')</script>"; 
      } else { 
          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // is this possible to move in another page?
            echo "I removed the Table here because it's not important";
            //Please any tips what I can add here?
        }// end of while 
    }//end of else 
// TO HERE

}//end of POST, setting up of variables

?>

<html>
<body>
    <form action="generate-csv.php" method="POST">
    <label>Month</label>
        <select>
        <option>JANUARY</option>
        <option>fEBRUARY</option>
        <option>MARCH</option>
        <option>so on...</option>
    </select>
    <label>Year</label>
        <select>
        <option>2015</option>
        <option>2014</option>
    </select>
    <label>Status</label>
        <select>
        <option>FRESH</option>
        <option>RENEWAL</option>
        <option>WINBACK</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="generate"  value="GENERATE">
    </form>
</body>
```

**generate.php**

```
            <?php
        include_once "dbconnect.php";
        include_once "report.php";

       //$sql will came from report.php 
        if($result = mysql_query($sql) ){
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {   
            $columns_total = mysql_num_fields($result);    

        // Get The Field Name
        for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
        $heading = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
        $output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
        }
        $output .="\n";                    
        }  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {
                            for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
        $output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
        }
        $output .="\n";
        }
        $filename = "myFile.csv";
        header('Content-type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        echo $output;
        exit;
        }?>
```

Comment: `$_GET` variable, `$_POST` variable or `$_SESSION` variable(s) can each solve your problem.

Comment: You can use `$_SESSION` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **report.php** store sql in `$_SESSION` variable.

```
//Put your code here.

$_SESSION['sql_query'] = $sql;

 //Is this possible to transfer to another page? I'll be using this for generate.csv
  //FROM here
  if ($result=mysql_query($sql)) {   
      $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
         if($query_num_rows == 0){ 
            echo "<script> alert('No Records Found!')</script>"; 
  } else { 
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // is this possible to move in another page?
        echo "I removed the Table here because it's not important";
        //Please any tips what I can add here?
    }// end of while 
}//end of else
```

and access it in **generate.php**

```
if($result = mysql_query($_SESSION['sql_query']) )   // first line of your code after include.
```

Comment: Hi sir, so I will delete this in **generate.php** ?  `<?php
        include_once "dbconnect.php";
        include_once "report.php";

       //$sql will came from report.php 
        if($result = mysql_query($sql) ){
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {   
            $columns_total = mysql_num_fields($result);   `

Comment: @JJ-SAMA you need to replace `if($result = mysql_query($sql) ){` code with `if($result = mysql_query($_SESSION['sql_query']) ) {` in your generate.php . rest will remain same. And if this answer works perfect for you them mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks, it's working but it also export  the`codes` in `report.php` into `csv`